# Change title of UINavigationController when UIPageViewController changes

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a storyboard in Xcode5 where I have a `UITabbarController` that has a `UINavigationController` which is linked to a `UIViewController`. From that last `UIViewController` the rest (`UIPageviewController` and `UITableViewController` is created programmatically in the respective classes. See the screenshot.

[image: Storyboard image of viewcontrollers] 

**The problem is setting the title of the `UINavigationController` when the page of the `UIPageViewController` changes. I want the title to reflect a `@property` on the `UITableViewController` class but I am not sure how to accomplish this.**

I have already tried using an `NSNotification` set in the `UITableViewController` but there is no method which gets called every time the user swipes to left or right for another page (when using the scroll type). I guess if I have a place to put the `NSNotification` so that it gets called every time the users changes the page it solves my problem.

Hopefully someone can give me a pointer where to look or what method or delegate to use.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had to do exactly this in the app I'm currently working on.

First ensure you have set self.pageViewController.delegate to self.

Here's what I did:

```
// Notice when the pageviewcontroller finishes animating between pages.
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
    didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished
   previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers
   transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed {

  // .viewControllers[0] is always (in my case at least) the 'current' viewController.
  UIViewController* vc = self.pageViewController.viewControllers[0];
  self.navigationItem.title = vc.navigationItem.title;
}
```

The 'secret' is that (at least in the simple swipe-left-right case with full-screen sized pages I have) that self.pageViewController.viewControllers[0] is the 'current' page.

To use your property rather than the navigationItem title, then just change the last line to something like self.navigationItem.title = ((MyViewController*)vc).myProperty;

Comment: Great this works as a charm! Thanks very much for the help. :)

Comment: No probs. Good luck with the app.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution was not working for me all the time. So an alternative solution could be using delegate,

```
protocol ChangeTitle {
    func changeTitle(title: String)
}
```

In the PagerController implement the protocol,

```
class MyPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, ChangeTitle {
func changeTitle(title: String) {
        self.navigationItem.title = title
    }
}
```

In the individual view controller of pagerviewcontroller,

```
var changeTitle: ChangeTitle?

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    changeTitle?.changeTitle(title: "whatever the title is")
}
```

You also have to assign `changeTitle` variable where you are creating the viewcontroller in pagerviewcontroller.